# How to create random number for a column in mysql with DEFAULT Constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

The DEFAULT constraint has no problem in accepting string or current date values. What i need is an constraint that will create an random 4 digit number every time an entity is created. I tried the following code but it returns an syntax error.

**ALTER TABLE client_number ADD(code INT(4) DEFAULT FLOOR(RAND()*9999)+1111);**

The above statement returns following error:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'floor(rand()*9999)+1111)' at line 1*

Need solution.

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) is quite clear:

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
> default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
> be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

The expression you have is not a constant, so it doesn't work. You would need to use a trigger instead.

Comment: Thank you for that, but is there a way to generate random 4 digit number inside sql while insertion?

Comment: @MeghashyamBhandary . . . You would need to use a trigger.  But why doesn't an auto-increment column work?

Comment: Auto increment just increases value by 1 and enter it to the column. I need an random number between 1111 and 9999.

Comment: @MeghashyamBhandary: You know that random numbers are not guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @dnoeth i don't need an unique number, that problem is solved by another column named id with auto increment.

Comment: what is the purpose of the random number column then?

Comment: random 4 digit number is used for client verification purpose.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff for suggesting trigger. I read about it just now. I found an solution.

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_code BEFORE INSERT ON client_number 
FOR EACH ROW SET @code=floor(rand()*9999)+1111;

Comment: I landed here because of a need for a simple random number default value (don't care if its unique) so that I can arbitrarily separate a table into 10 piles for a process where I'd like to load level.  Having a simple random integer is a simple method which nearly assures a balanced distribution.

Comment: @cpopolo . . . Just use an `id` column and use modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below query

ALTER TABLE `table_name`  ADD `field_name` INT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT (rand() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000)  AFTER `some_feild`;

The result gives a random number between 1000-9999  [image]